# Retrieving clicked state of bootstrap checkbox

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have the following bootstrap HTML code and I want to identify whether the checkbox is clicked or not.
I tried the following code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function() {
  alert($('#myCheckbox').hasClass('selected'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      A test checkbox
    </label>
  </div>
  <div type="button" id="myButton">Press me</div>
</div>
```

However it always returns `false`, regardless of the state of the `checkbox`.

`alert($('#myCheckbox').hasClass('active'));` also returns `false`.

Note that I tried using the DOM Explorer to see what changes when the checkbox is selected and deselected, and I could not see any change. I imagine this is part of my problem - if the answerer could explain this as well it would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `is(':checked')`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function() {
  alert($('#myCheckbox').is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      A test checkbox
    </label>
  </div>
  <div type="button" id="myButton">Press me</div>
</div>
```